# Create a Gmail account in Django using Python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, gmail

I'm working on a Django project and wanted its users to have the ability to create a Gmail account directly through our site.

Is anyone familiar with a way to do so?

If not, I was thinking of embedding Google's account creation page directly into the Django site, but I'm still unsure of how to do that.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: By Gmail account do you mean a free Gmail account or a GSuite one?

Comment: Just a free Gmail account.

Comment: I don't think Gmail has an API for that, they are pretty strict in terms of account generation. You might try using an IFRAME (and even that may not work because of CORS).